# Code in radio button handler seems to be wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong about this javascript code. I have 4 radio buttons in a line. By default the first one is clicked. Now when I click the third one, it does not jump to the third one. I do not know why. I also see not error in the developer console.

```
function funcCancelClose(testcaseId,update)
{
   if(update == false)
   {
        modalCloseCancel(testcaseId);
   }
   else
   {
        modalCloseCancelUpdate(testcaseId, $("#radio-previous_"+testcaseId).val());
   }
}


$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
var testcaseId = this.name;
var update = $("#row_"+testcaseId).attr("attr-resultid") == -1 ? false : true;
//Start of problematic code
$("#modalCancel").off();
$("#modalClose").off();
$("#modalCancel,#modalClose").click(funcCancelClose(testcaseId,update));
//End of problematic code

$("#btnModalNOKorNA").trigger("click");
}
```

**if I make testcaseId and update global I do not have this issue**

```
        var testcaseId;
        var update;

        $("#modalCancel,#modalClose").click(function()
        {
           if(update == false)
           {
                modalCloseCancel(testcaseId);
           }
           else
           {
                modalCloseCancelUpdate(testcaseId, $("#radio-previous_"+testcaseId).val());
           }
        });

        //Enter test result fast
        $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {

            testcaseId = this.name;
            update = $("#row_"+testcaseId).attr("attr-resultid") == -1 ? false : true;

         }
```

Comment: please add relevant html code also

Comment: can you now help me? Why does first code not work ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/UTwGS/

HTML:

```
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="my-radio">Radio One</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="2" name="my-radio">Radio One</label>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click change', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

Comment: I do know what is problem in my code. Your code is different

Comment: I don't think that would help . It is just 4 radio buttons.